# Angular Array Prototype

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following declared in an Angular Application:

```
export {}; // Using the export, there is no need to import the file anywhere.

declare global {
     interface Array<T> {
        firstOrDefault(predicate: Function) : Array<T>;
    }
}

if (!Array.prototype.firstOrDefault) {
     Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function(predicate: Function){
        return this.reduce( (accumulator, currentValue) => {
            if(!accumulator && predicate(currentValue)) 
            accumulator = currentValue;
        
            return accumulator;
         }, null);
    }
}
```

This is declared in a folder /src/app/shared/prototypes/linq.ts as part of the shared module. However this is not explicitly added in the shared.module.ts.

I added the declaration to the tsconfig.json to be

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["./src/app/shared/Prototypes"]
  }
}
```

Also I have added the declaration to tsconfig.app.json to be

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts",
    "src/app/shared/Prototypes/Linq.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Everything is building fine but whenever it runs I get an error, "firstOrDefault is not a function."

Can anyone help?

Comment: Move the polyfill somewhere else and remove the `export {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make it simpler:

```
interface Array<T> {
    firstOrDefault(predicate: Function) : Array<T>;
}
```

```
Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function(predicate: function) {
        return this.reduce( (accumulator, currentValue) => {
            if(!accumulator && predicate(currentValue)) 
            accumulator = currentValue;
        
            return accumulator;
         }, null);
}
```

finally import the file there in app.module.ts

```
import './shared/prototypes/linq'
```

it worked for me